# How to create a module that changes other modules' behaviors

Tags: module, socialengine

I want to create a module for SocialEngine that changes the signup behavior by adding the option to signup using phone number and sending text message to the user's phone and letting them confirm it. I guess I need to add code in the file application/modules/User/Form/Signup.php. For example, I can add a new field as follows:

```
$this->AddElement('Text', 'sms', [
    'class' => 'signup-name',
    'label' => 'Phone Number',
    'required' => true,
    'validators' => [
        ['StringLength', true, ['min'=>11, 'max'=>11]]
    ]
        ]
);

$this->sms->getValidator('StringLength')->setMessage('Phone must be 11 digits');
```

However, I don't want to manually add the code. I need to add the functionality by installing the plugin and disable it by removing or disabling the plugin. How can I do that?
Do I need to mess with installation php scripts and do file operations like overwriting files or is there a better way to separate my files completely, meanwhile making them serve as a complement for a given module?

Comment: If this is only validator message, please add in existing code. If you still want to create a new module, there will be a lot of changes you have to do. You need to copy and filed module and crate yours and need to make changes in bootstraps file so fetch your modules rather than default.

Comment: Yes, this is just a field that I am adding to the signup form. Can I add this change as a new functionality in a new module so that it appears in the signup process if the module is enabled?

Comment: you can create new module and can add your process in sign up. Check engine4_users_signup table